# Unable to delete file through function in Scilab

Tags: function, file, delete-file, scilab

I have written the following code to plot a graph with the data present in the 'datafile'. After the graph has been plotted, I want to delete the file.

```
function plot_torque(datafile)
    //This will call a datafile and plot the graph of net_torque vs. time
    verbose = 1;
    // Columns to plot
    x_col = 1;
    y_col = 2;
    // open the datafile
    file1 = file('open', datafile,'old');
    data1 = read(file1, -1, 4);
    time = data1(:,x_col);
    torque = data1(:,y_col);
    plot(time, torque, '.-b');
    xtitle("Torque Generated vs. Time" ,"Time(s)" , "Torque Generated(Nm/m)");
    file('close',file());
    //%________________%
endfunction
```

In the place that I have marked as //%________% I have tried

```
deletefile(datafile);
```

and

```
mdelete(datafile);
```

None of them have worked. 
And I have set the working directory to where the above '.sci' file is present and the 'datafile' is present. I am using scilab-5.4.1.

Comment: What return function deletefile  when trying remove? Try to specify an absolute file path.

Answer (score 0):

You probably leave (left) the file open. Try this:

```
fil="d:\Attila\PROJECTS\Scilab\Stackoverflow\file_to_delete.txt";  //change it!
fprintfMat(fil,rand(3,3),"%.2g");  //fill with some data

fd=mopen(fil,"r");  //open
//do something with the file

mclose(fd);   //close
//if you neglect (comment out) this previous line, the file remains open, 
//and scilab can not delete it!
//If you made this "mistake", first you should close it by executing:
//  mclose("all");
//otherwise the file remains open until you close (and restart) Scilab!

mdelete(fil);   //this works for me
```